# CartItem matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

So I get CartItem matching query does not exist error when I try to add to cart, I'm trying to check if the user already has that item in their cart and if they do not then it is supposed to be added, if they do then it will not be added again, When i click add to cart it gives me CartItem matching query does not exist.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.db import IntegrityError
from .models import Book, CartItem
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import BookForm
# Create your views here.



def calculate(request):
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    fianlprice = 0
    for item in oof:
        fianlprice += item.book.price

        


def signupuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html')
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                    user.save()
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request, 'main/UserCreated.html')
                except IntegrityError:
                    return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'That username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'})
            else:
                return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Passwords did not match'})

def signinuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html', {'error':'You are already logged in'})
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm()})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
            if user is None:
                return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm(), 'error':'Username and password did not match'})
            else:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'main/loggedin.html', {'error':'You are now logged in!'})
 
def logoutuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET": 
            return render(request, 'main/logoutuser.html')
        elif request.method == "POST":
            logout(request)
            return render(request, 'main/loggedin.html', {'error':'You are now logged out!'})
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html', {'error':'You are not logged in'})
    

def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        fianlprice = 0
        for item in oof:
            fianlprice += item.book.price
        books = Book.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'books':books, 'price':fianlprice})
    else:
        books = Book.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'books':books})


@login_required
def addtocart(request):
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    fianlprice = 0
    for item in oof:
        fianlprice += item.book.price
    books = Book.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not CartItem.objects.get(user=request.user, book=Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])):
            try:
                book = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])
            except Book.DoesNotExist:
                return redirect('home')
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(book=book, user=request.user)
            return redirect('home')
            
        else:
            return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'books':books, 'error':'That book is already in your cart!', 'price':fianlprice})
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':BookForm})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class CartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

urls.py

```
"""EBook URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from core import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/', views.signupuser, name='signupuser'),
    path('login/', views.signinuser, name='signinuser'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutuser, name='logoutuser'),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('cart/', views.addtocart, name='cart'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

home.html

```
<h1>Here are products</h1>
<h1>{{ error }}</h1>
<h1>Your cart currently costs ${{ price }}</h1>
{% for book in books %}
<h3>{{ book.name }}</h3>
<img src= "/media/{{ book.image }}" alt="">
<p>{{ book.description }}</p>
<form method="POST" action="/cart/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="bookid" value="{{ book.id }}">Add to cart</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not CartItem.objects.get(user=request.user, book=Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])):
 # there your code is breaking


cart_item_instance_qs = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user, book=Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid']))

if cart_item_instance_qs.exists():
    
    ..... do your stuff
```

when you try to get element which does not exist in the DB django throws that error

In the future try to use `.exists()` then select the element it wont throw you an error + you have more control

if `exists()` returns `True` you can select the first element with

```
cart_item_instance = cart_item_instance_qs.first()
```

you can check the count

```
cart_item_instance_qs.count()
```

or you can loop through the elements